# Pass keydown event to another textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, textbox, keydown

I'm trying to pass an `keydown` event from one textbox to another. What I mean with this is that if you, for example, press the 'a' key, some code should simulate that key as being pressed in the second textbox.

I do not want to just copy the value of the first textbox into the second - it should be on a per-key basis so to say. Suppose the first textbox contains `abc` and the second textbox is empty, when you then press the 'd' key in textbox 1, textbox 2 should only contain `d`.

What I already tried is (http://jsfiddle.net/E5qyr/1/):

```
$('#t1').keydown(function(e) {
    $('#t2').keydown(e);
});
```

But this does not work (I guess I'm thinking too simple). I know I could append the character pressed by looking at `e.keyCode`, but also 'backspace' etc. has to be working.

Does anybody have an idea to pass a `keydown` event from one textbox to another?

Comment: Could you explain more of the situation as to why you need to have two textboxes in sync. There are a few solutions to this problem, but a lot of it depends on your particular reasonings.

Comment: @Ballsacian: To be honest, I must say I'm just playing around a bit with jQuery, so as to get more feeling for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textarea elements don't have listeners automatically installed to them, so triggering a 'keydown' event for the #t2 will not show a response. What you want is to just add the text you get from the #t1 keydown event (of which you are listening) and append it to your #t2.

**UPDATED with support for backspace. Other codes found [here](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/What-is-the-list-of-KeyCodes-for-JavaScript-KeyDown-KeyPress-and-KeyUp-events.aspx).**

Example:

```
$('#t1').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 8) { //Backspace
      this.text(this.val().substr(0, this.val().length - 1));
    } else {
      $('#t2').append($('#t1').val());
      this.empty();
    }
});
```

Comment: That's indeed what I want, but how to handle backspace in this case?

Comment: You would just need to put a quick condition to check the `e.which` to get the keycode and compare it to the keycode for a backspace. I'll update when I find it.

Comment: @Stephen Don't use `$('#t1')` inside its own event handler. Use `this`.

Comment: `append` and `value` is not working for some reason, first of all it's `val` and instead of `append` I'm trying to use `val($('#t2').val() + $('#t2').val())`.

Comment: Thanks Šime. Don't usually code in jquery so I didn't catch that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/E5qyr/3/. `append` isn't working for setting the value apparently.

Comment: Yeah, was a little off the cuff but it seems to work for you. Glad to be able to help.

Comment: I would be careful when dealing with keycodes. Not all browsers pass the same codes and it can be hard to determine exactly what was pressed sometimes.

http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: @Ballsacian1: the `e.which` part of the code is a jQuery function that tries to unify the different browser codes. Right now, no one solution is 100% but `e.which` is the closest that I've found.

Answer (score 0):

Why not replace textbox value onkeydown?  It seems it would be more simples to just do `txt1.text = txt2.text` instead of appending the existing strings in txt1.

Comment: v What about the BACKSPACE key? Read the question thoroughly.

Comment: As I stated, I actually don't want to just copy the text.

Comment: Just ran a test and backspace was captured in onkeyup and onkeydown.
`document.getElementById("txt1").onkeyup = function () {
        txt2.text = txt1.text;
    };`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('#t1').keydown(function(e) {
    var char = (e.keyCode == 8) ? '' : String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode + (e.shiftKey ? 0 : 32));
    $('#t2').val(char);
});
```

Comment: No, I'm afraid. That replaces the value of `t2`, and `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)` doesn't always return the correct character. For example the 'a' key is 97 and the char code would be the one of 97+32, which is an empty string.

Comment: @pimvdb that's why I have `(e.shiftKey ? 0 : 32)` there to check if the shiftKey is pressed. What I got from "when you then press the 'd' key in textbox 1, textbox 2 should only contain d" is that whatever key you enter should replace the value in #t2.  Edit: Never mind I get it.